# Asp.net web forms - couldn't tell how the hyperlink is redirecting to a popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, dynamic, webforms

I am currently working on a legacy system that was developed decades ago. To populate data in a grid it uses

```
   <asp:Repeater></asp:Repeater>
```

Within the

```
   <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
```

section it has

```
  <asp:HyperLink ID="ItemId" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

This link redirects to a popup window which redirects to a certain url. The part I don't understand is, where that clickable event is set? Any idea?

Comment: can you please check the C# code for the repeater data bind

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section with the header "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". Your current title doesn't do that.

Comment: The data bind is working perfectly, I kind of got that part. But, once the bind is done, the ItemId column shows clickable Id's. When you click it, it just opens a popup. I even wanted to put a debugging break point, couldn't locate where?

Comment: @HereticMonkey done.

Comment: So, there's some code somewhere that's setting a click event handler for that `HyperLink` control. If you think that a bunch of people on the internet with no access to your source code are going to have a better idea than you, you have another think coming :).

Comment: Does the asp:Hyperlink control has the NavigateUrl property? that is the event you are looking for.https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/02/aspnet-hyperlink-example-how-to-use.html

Comment: If you are not seeing it in the Repeater's ItemDataBound event, then it could getting set via Javascript but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Within aspx.cs code behind there is repeater_ItemDataBond method where the url for the hyperlink is set. But, the event that opens the popup was javaScript which was formatted using a StringBuilder.

Thank you all for your comments and the clues you provided.